# Get $a=((r-s)((k-l)^{-1}\bmod{p}))\bmod{p}$ from $r=(ak+b) \bmod{p}$, $s=(al+b) \bmod{p}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was trying to solve some modulus equations and got stuck at the following:

Given, $r=(ak+b) \bmod{p}$, $s=(al+b) \bmod{p}$. Also given that $k\ne l$ and $a \ne 0$. Also $a,b, k$ are integers and $p$ is prime.

**Question 1**: How we can get $b=(r-ak) \bmod{p}$ please?

**Question 2**:: Equivalently, how to get $a=((r-s)((k-l)^{-1}\bmod{p}))\bmod{p}$ please?

**Solution 2**: I solved $a=((r-s)((k-l)^{-1}\bmod{p}))\bmod{p}$  as follows, but:

I see that ,
\begin{align*}
 r=(ak+b) \bmod{p}\\
s=(al+b) \bmod{p}\\
r-s = (ak+b-al-b) \bmod{p}\\
r-s = (a(k-l)) \bmod{p}\\
(r-s)(k-l)^{-1} = (a) \bmod{p}\\
(r-s)(k-l)^{-1} \bmod{p} = a\\
\end{align*}

The solution I got was $a=((r-s)((k-l)^{-1}\bmod{p}))\bmod{p}$, so one extra $\bmod{p}$ is missing. Can you please correct me? And also is it legal to move variables from left side to right side as I did?

Comment: Hint:  $$r \equiv (ak + b) \pmod p \iff r - ak \equiv b \pmod p \iff b \equiv (r - ak) \pmod p.$$

Comment: @Avra , notice that $a \equiv x \pmod{k}, b \equiv y \pmod{k} \implies a - b \equiv x - y \pmod{k}$, so you can subtract $ak$ from both sides of your equation, which is valid.

Comment: Or, when you look at your equation, see that $r \equiv ak + b \pmod{p} \implies r = px + ak + b \implies r - ak = px + b \implies r - ak \equiv b \pmod{p}$

Comment: @Spectre. Thank you. How we got the second $\bmod{p}$ please above?

Comment: @Avra I think I may find it hard, as I am still at the basics, but perhaps you may work it out if you use the same methodology of analysis as I have used above