# Showing there is a one-to-one correspondence between $(a,b)$ and $(r,s)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was trying to solve some modulus equations and got stuck at proving that there is a one-to-one correspondence between pairs $(a,b)$ and $(r,s)$:

Given, $r=(ak+b) \bmod{p}$, $s=(al+b) \bmod{p}$. Also given that $k\ne l$ and $a \ne 0$. Also $a,b, k, l$ are integers and $p$ is prime. We are also given that there are $(p)(p-1)$ possible pairs of $(r,s)$ or $(a,b)$ since $r\ne s$. Also, $k,l \in [0, \cdots, p-1]$ and assume that $k, l$ are distinct.

We can also see that distinct values $k,l$ map to distinct $r,s$. So:

$$r-s \equiv a(k-l) \bmod{p}$$

To get $a=((r-s)((k-l)^{-1}\bmod{p}))\bmod{p}$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
 r=(ak+b) \bmod{p}\\
s=(al+b) \bmod{p}\\
r-s = (ak+b-al-b) \bmod{p}\\
r-s = (a(k-l)) \bmod{p}\\
(r-s)((k-l)^{-1} \bmod{p}) = (a) \bmod{p}\\
(r-s)((k-l)^{-1} \bmod{p}) \bmod{p} = a\\
\end{align*}

Equivalently, we can get $b=(r-ak) \bmod{p}$.

**Problem**: I got stuck at showing there is a one-to-one correspondence between pairs $(a,b)$ and $(r,s)$ please.

**Edit**: $k,l$ are indeed fixed.

Comment: Wasn't this problem posted here a few hours ago? Ah, here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237777/get-a-r-sk-l-1-bmodp-bmodp-from-r-akb-bmodp-s-alb – why have you done this?

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Thanks. That was different as I was stuck at finding $a, b$. Here I am asking for one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: OK. But you should link each question to the other, when they are so closely related.

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Thanks. I should add link above please?

Comment: Yes, you should, along with the explanation of how this question differs from that one.

Comment: For this question to make sense $k$ and $l$ need to be fixed mod $p$. If not, then I don't think there can be a 1-1 correspondence. If that is an assumption of the question, then I think it should be stated.

Comment: @robjohn. Thank you very much. I see that. They are indeed fixed! Why that is the case please?

Comment: @Avra: why is it the case that if $k$ and $l$ are not fixed, that there is not a 1-1 correspondence? If that were not the case, then $(k-l)^{-1}$ is unknown and there would be no way to compute $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given
$$
\begin{align}
r&\equiv ak+b&\pmod{p}\\
s&\equiv al+b&\pmod{p}
\end{align}\tag1
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
r-s&\equiv a(k-l)&\pmod{p}\\
ks-lr&\equiv b(k-l)&\pmod{p}
\end{align}\tag2
$$
If $(k-l,p)=1$ (which is the case if $p$ is prime and $0\le k\ne l\lt p$), then $(k-l)^{-1}$ is well-defined mod $p$, and then we can compute
$$
\begin{align}
a&\equiv(r-s)(k-l)^{-1}&\pmod{p}\\
b&\equiv(ks-lr)(k-l)^{-1}&\pmod{p}
\end{align}\tag3
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. So, can you give hint how to prove then the one-to-one correspondence please?

Comment: $(1)$ gives $(a,b)\mapsto(r,s)$ and $(3)$ gives $(r,s)\mapsto(a,b)$. What more do you need to show a 1-1 correspondence?

Comment: Yes to show a 1-1 correspondence please?

Comment: I have given a 1-1 correspondence, once in the answer and again in a comment.

Comment: Sorry. Thank you for the amazing explanation! I see that.

Comment: Finally, what is meant here please by "If $(k-l,p)=1$"?

Comment: $(a,b)$ is often used to mean the [GCD of $a$ and $b$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor), so that means that $k-l$ and $p$ are [relatively prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers).